# dispatch is not defined/store is not defined in actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my actions in my react redux applications when I'm trying to dispatch an action I'm getting the dispatch is not defined no-undef error message. When I change dispatch to store.dispatch I'm then getting the same message for store. my store is configured as so:

```js
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__COMPOSE|| compose;
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route  component={App}/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
register();
```

I have my action set up as so:

```js
export function login(email,password){
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
  let data= JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password
  });
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  };


  return function(dispatch){
    return fetch(url,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers:headers,
      body: data
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
            alert("login failed");
          } else {
            return res.json();
          }
    })
  }
  .then(json=>{
    localStorage.setItem('token',json.token)
    dispatch({type:SET_USER, user:json.user})
  })
}
```

and my reducers set up:

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

 function userReducer(state=null,action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'SET_USER':
      return action.user
    default:
      return state
  }
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user:userReducer
})
export default rootReducer
```

I;ve been through the docs and have not found an answer and this set up is very similar to the last application I built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
export function login(email,password){
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
  let data= JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password
  });
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  };


  return function(dispatch){
    return fetch(url,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers:headers,
      body: data
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
            alert("login failed");
          } else {
            return res.json();
          }
    })
    .then(json=>{
      localStorage.setItem('token',json.token)
      dispatch({type:SET_USER, user:json.user})
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Yup, it was a syntax error, the then was chaining from the parent function instead of the fetch. Thanks!